# ins-32025 oracle 11g error for windows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to install Oracle onto my VM for the **first (1st)** time, however, when I get to the setting install directories, I keep getting the following error:

[INS-32025 Oracle 11g Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37z9c.png)

I have tried changing the install from C: to D: but I keep getting the same error.
Google isn't of any help in this situation. The best I can find is to clear previous Oracle install data, but as I've said, this is the first time oracle is being installed onto my VM.

The VM is windows 7 32bit and I am using the 32bit installer for oracle, just for clarity sake.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Find registry variable called  `inst_loc` which will points to Oracle Inventory location. Then delete the content of Inventory directory as well as the registry variable.

Comment: @JSapkota Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but there is no variable that points to any oracle inventory in my registry.

Comment: Run--> Type 'regedit'--> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE-->ORACLE (Clieck on Oracle and you will see the variable with the location data.

Answer (score 9):

I received the same error and it got resolved when i removed the line that contain  new oracle home in  inventory.xml file.

For windows, you can get the file at **C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\ContentsXML**. Under this folder you should see the file **inventory.xml**. Just open this file and remove the line which contains the new oracle home path. For more information, that variable you can find after *HOME_LIST*. Just remove the complete line.

Comment: Also worth noting that once you delete that line, you'll need to exit and restart the installation process again.

Comment: @TonyKlotz, you shouldn't be needed to restart the installation. Just reload the file or reboot the machine or try with restarting oracle services.

Comment: Faced similar issue during re-installation of oracle 12c.                                 The resolution is same.Following link also helped:                               http://dba-story.blogspot.com/2014/04/ins-32025-chosen-installation-conflicts.html .                                                                                                 And also I needed to exit and re-start the installation.